# Caching of numba functions leads to error

Tags: python, numba

Whenever I use caching on a function, ..

```
@jit(cache=True)
def test(x):
    return x
```

.. I get a RuntimeError similar to ..

> RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'test.test': no locator available for file '/tmp/ipykernel_3392909/373547737.py'

.. and yes, `/tmp` should be writable (`rwxrwxrwt`).

Whats happening here?

Comment: do you have to run this programme in the temp folder?

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege No

Comment: So simply run it outside the temp folder and it should work

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I just had a double check and it's not residing in `/tmp`. And the env. variable `NUMBA_CACHE_DIR` is set to `'/home/username/.cache/ipython'` what seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been caused by a mix-up of `conda` and `pip`. I thought `conda` would prevent that, but no.
After having wiped pip and conda completely, it now works by using conda alone.

Additionally, there seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7798) involved.

Advice to the outside world: Don't use conda if you don't have a special reason to.

Answer (score 0):

One file is cached by another.

When @jit compiles a function, it creates a '.py' file with the same name that contains the bytecode of that function.
At every call to `test`, Numba tries to use this file and it fails because there is no locator for this file in the cache.
This [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3742) has been reported already.

Comment: I don't think, I understand the explanation ... 
And apart from that, what can I do about it?

Comment: I think you need to do a manual check because the file is created when the function is cached, not when it's called. Look at the cache file(s) that are in your directory, and try to open them as Python code to see what's going on. Sorry for the late reply